# Gereralized function with 2nd species singularity integrable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, continuity

Is this ""distribution""
$$
u(t) = 0\; \text{ if }\; t\neq 0
$$
$$ 
u(t) = \infty \; \text{ if } t=0
$$

is integrable (with respect to the Lebesgue measure ) ?

If u(t) is finite at $t=1$ then there is no problem because u is equal to the zero function almost everywhere so it's integrable.
But here $u(0)=\infty$ ... can we use the same argument ? This function is not even in $L^1_{loc}$ so we can't associate a regular distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to talk about distributions here. This is a simple function, taking its values in $[0,+\infty]$, which is common in measure theory.

To answer your question, yes you can use the same argument. This function is equal to $0$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere, so it's integrable.